# Is it possible to have only newly added rows into another table on a fixed time in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I have two table(T_1 & T_2) with same fields. What I need, after every hour T_2 table only have the data which was inserted on T_1 table within that hour(previous hour data will be erased). I am using sql server. Please help me.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to do incremental replication. There are many solutions for this but they depend on your constraints. What database platform is this? (SQL Server? Oracle?) Is there a modified date on the records? can you add one? Are the source and target databases on the same server?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am using sql server, there is no modified date in T_1 table and I can't add any column on that table. I can't understand your last questions. Those two table are in same DB.

Comment: I'll add the SQL Server tag. _please_ ensure you use a specific tag in future questions. What is the purpose of copying records from one table to another every hour? Please edit your question and explain why you are doing this - it makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you set up two tables to do this?

Your use-case seems like a canonical case for [table partitioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-ver15).  This is a way of storing data in separate "units" (files).  You seem to want `T_1` to have its data split by hour.

Then you can directly access the data for a particular hour.  This will be as efficient from an access perspective as copying the data into a separate table.

If you really wanted to, you could copy the most recent partition to another table every hour -- swapping in the new data for the older data.  But that seems unnecessary in practice.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. There is no date time column in those tables. Can you please suggest me how can I do partitioning?

Comment: @AloukikRoy . . . How are you going to get the most recent hour if you don't have a date/time column?  You need to revisit your data model.